# Is it appropriate to close a question as a duplicate of another closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

So, I voted to close [Headphones while cycling](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/headphones-while-cycling) as a duplicate of [Is listening to music dangerous while cycling?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/623/is-listening-to-music-dangerous-while-cycling)

However, the other question was closed (due to being unconstructive).  Mostly because the topic inspires opinionated responses kind of like chain lubrication or helmet wearing.

Should we let the new entry open, close both, or re-open the original?

Answer (score 5):

Well...

The core of the newer question is:

> has anyone ever had an accident while wearing headphones that could have been avoided if they hadnt had them on, or has anyone had a near miss without headphones that would have been an accident if they had have had headphones on??

The current answers are 2 straight-up opinions that don't really answer the question and 2 anecdotes that reach opposite conclusions. No answers based on real data... And that's what came in within 4 hours... That pretty much seals it that the question is "not constructive", to me...

**My opinion: both should be closed.**

There's some differences in what's being asked that I think mean the new question really isn't a duplicate of the old question. The new one seems like maybe it could be changed into something more constructive, perhaps asking for scientific studies instead of anecdotes...

**General Rule:** If the new question duplicates the old question and is a candidate for closure (not constructive, etc), it's appropriate to close it as a duplicate of the old question.

Comment: FYI: it's currently closed as not-constructive